# Str_Replace Without Recalling the Function

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

How can I use str_replace in PHP without allowing it to re-replace the characters that have been used in the $replace_with in the following code?

```
<?php
 $string='abcd';
 $replace= array('a','c');
 $replace_with = '[ac]';
 $string=str_replace($replace,$replace_with,$string);
 echo $string;
?>
```

The result would be:
"**[a[ac]]b[ac]d**"
How can I force my script to replace the '**a**' in $string with '**[ac]**' once only without allowing it to replace the '**c**' inside the newly inserted '**[ac]**'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) does precisely what you ask:

```
$string = strtr( $string, array( 'a'=>'[ac]', 'c'=>'[ac]' ) );
```

Output:

```
[ac]b[ac]d
```

Relevant excerpt:

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. **Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.**

Comment: I didn't know such a function exists. Thank you so much.